# If Concat insert result

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have a problem, I am making an insert using the concat to generate multiple inserts, however I realize that a null field is affecting all the queries, since the records that have null in their field, their insert is not generated correctly , now when integrating an IF() validation in the value of the field where the problem is caused, mysql sends me an error therefore the query is not executed

[image]

This is my query insert

```
SELECT concat ( "INSERT INTO `erp_gamma`.`partner` (`n_partner_id`, `n_activo`, `c_apellido_materno`, `c_apellido_paterno`, `c_correo_electronico`, `n_dias_credito`, `c_identificador`, `c_json`, `d_limite_credito`, `c_nombre`, `n_persona_fisica`, `c_razon_social`, `c_rfc`, `n_status`, `n_corporativo_sucursal_id`, `n_partner_tipo_id`, `c_codigo_postal`, `n_numero_telefonico`, `create_date`, `update_date`, `c_cp_fiscal`, `c_regimen_fiscal`, `c_sistema_id_serie_numerico`, `n_sistema_id_numerico`, `c_id_migracion`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '",partner.contacto_nombre,"', '",partner.contacto_nombre,"', '",partner.contacto_email,"', '",partner.control_dias_credito,"', '11111', '{\"id_calle_cliente_md\":\"",partner.contacto_calle,"\",\"id_colonia_cliente_md\":\"",partner.contacto_colonia,"\",\"id_ciudad_cliente_md\":\"",partner.contacto_ciudad,"\",\"id_estado_cliente_md\":\"",partner.contacto_estado,"\",\"id_cp_cliente_md\":\"",partner.contacto_cp,"\",\"id_telefono2_cliente_md\":\"",partner.contacto_telefono2,"\",\"id_celular_cliente_md\":\"",partner.contacto_telefono3,"\",\"id_fax_cliente_md\":\"",partner.contacto_fax,"\",\"id_web_cliente_md\":\"",partner.contacto_web,"\",\"id_tipoprecio_cliente_md\":\"",partner.control_tipo_precio_default,"\",\"id_calle_rfc_cliente_md\":\"",partner.factura_calle,"\",\"id_colonia_rfc_cliente_md\":\"",partner.factura_colonia,"\",\"id_ciudad_rfc_cliente_md\":\"",partner.factura_ciudad,"\",\"id_estado_rfc_cliente_md\":\"",partner.factura_estado,"\"}', '",partner.control_limite_credito,"', '",partner.contacto_nombre,"', '1', '",partner.factura_nombre,"', '",partner.factura_rfc,"', '1', '122', '1', '",partner.contacto_cp,"', '",partner.contacto_telefono1,"', now(), now(), '",partner.factura_cp,"', "IF(partner.factura_regimen_fiscal IS NULL," ", partner.factura_regimen_fiscal)", 'TP1_20', '20', '",partner.sku,"' );")
FROM partner
WHERE partner.tipo_partner = 1 AND partner.status =1;
```

[image: Error MySQL]

I hope the inserts can be generated with the records I need

Answer (score 0):

I post the query as it is as i never can test it

i added a lot of spaces, but i think  it is more a problem from mysql workbench, as that big concat, aren't usually done, so the parser will get into trouble

The misstale you made is that you have is

```
IF(partner.factura_regimen_fiscal IS NULL," ", partner.factura_regimen_fiscal)
```

must be in commas, as it is ntpart if the string that you are combining

```
SELECT concat ( "INSERT INTO `erp_gamma`.`partner` (`n_partner_id`, `n_activo`, `c_apellido_materno`, `c_apellido_paterno`, `c_correo_electronico`, `n_dias_credito`, `c_identificador`, `c_json`, `d_limite_credito`, `c_nombre`, `n_persona_fisica`, `c_razon_social`, `c_rfc`, `n_status`, `n_corporativo_sucursal_id`, `n_partner_tipo_id`, `c_codigo_postal`, `n_numero_telefonico`, `create_date`, `update_date`, `c_cp_fiscal`, `c_regimen_fiscal`, `c_sistema_id_serie_numerico`, `n_sistema_id_numerico`, `c_id_migracion`) VALUES (NULL, '1', '"
,partner.contacto_nombre,"', '",partner.contacto_nombre,"', '",partner.contacto_email,"', '"
,partner.control_dias_credito,"', '11111', '{\"id_calle_cliente_md\":\" "
,partner.contacto_calle,"\",\"id_colonia_cliente_md\":\" "
,partner.contacto_colonia," \",\"id_ciudad_cliente_md\":\" ",partner.contacto_ciudad," \",\"id_estado_cliente_md\":\" "
,partner.contacto_estado,"\",\"id_cp_cliente_md\":\" ",partner.contacto_cp," \",\"id_telefono2_cliente_md\":\" "
,partner.contacto_telefono2," \",\"id_celular_cliente_md\":\" ",partner.contacto_telefono3," \",\"id_fax_cliente_md\":\" "
,partner.contacto_fax," \",\"id_web_cliente_md\":\" ",partner.contacto_web," \",\"id_tipoprecio_cliente_md\":\" "
,partner.control_tipo_precio_default," \",\"id_calle_rfc_cliente_md\":\" ",partner.factura_calle," \",\"id_colonia_rfc_cliente_md\":\" "
,partner.factura_colonia," \",\"id_ciudad_rfc_cliente_md\":\" ",partner.factura_ciudad," \",\"id_estado_rfc_cliente_md\":\" "
,partner.factura_estado," \"}', ' ",partner.control_limite_credito,"', '",partner.contacto_nombre
,"', '1', '",partner.factura_nombre,"', '",partner.factura_rfc,"', '1', '122', '1', '"
,partner.contacto_cp,"', '",partner.contacto_telefono1,"', now(), now(), '"
,partner.factura_cp,"', ",IF(partner.factura_regimen_fiscal IS NULL," ", partner.factura_regimen_fiscal),", 'TP1_20', '20', '",partner.sku,"' );")
FROM partner
WHERE partner.tipo_partner = 1 AND partner.status =1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a case statement formatted something like this;

case when partner.factura_regimen_fiscal IS NULL then "" else
partner.factura_regimen_fiscal end